# Deleted Administrator

Tags: permissions, user, roles, admin, civicrm-spark

I accidentally removed the administrator role from myself, and now I can't get into my site. When I try to log in, I get the access denied message. If anyone knows a workaround for fixing my silly mistake, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: What CMS are you using as I suspect that will matter for the solution.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include that! I am on Spark with CiviCRM hosting.

Comment: I pinged someone who may be able to help

Comment: Hi Liz, I added back the administrator role to your account. For these kind of administrative requests, please do not hesitate to contact us at spark@civicrm.org.